# Parsing JFormattedTextField, manipulating data and parsing back to String

Tags: java

I am working on a project at work and having some problems with parsing a number. I'm not sure why I am getting the odd results I am.

To start I have a JFormattedText field that holds a 12-digit number, like so:

```
referenceNumberField = new JFormattedTextField(nf);
        referenceNumberField.setText("371260062101009");
        referenceNumberField.setColumns(12);
        panel5.add(referenceNumberField);
```

There is a loop further in my program that causes this number to be written an indefinite amount of times. I have been asked to ensure that the number is different each time it is written without changing the amount of digits. To do this I decided to add the current counter value to the number each run, thus it will always be different but remain 12 digits.

To start I attempted to parse the JFormattedTextField into a String.

```
String referenceStartingString = referenceNumberField.getText();
```

This part works correctly. Next I want to turn it into a double so I can manipulate it.

```
double referenceNumberDouble = Double.parseDouble(referenceStartingString);
                    System.out.println("Reference Number Double: "+referenceNumberDouble);
```

The problem I'm having really lies here. The result I get from runtime is this:

```
Reference Number Double: 3.71260062101009E14
```

I'm not sure why the decimal has been added nor am I sure why exactly the "E" is in the number. I thought that stood for exponent and only shows up if the number exceeds the limit for double (Which I do not think this does)..

Just to clarify the next stages are

Turning my counter into a double

```
double countDouble = (double) j;
```

Adding the two together:

```
double referenceTotal = referenceNumberDouble + countDouble;
```

and turning back into a String..

```
String referenceString = String.valueOf(referenceTotal);
```

Without being able to turn the string into a double I can't go any further, I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The E means `*10^`. This is because int has a maximal value of about 2000000000. Try parsing to long instead of int.
`Long.parselong()`

Comment: Thanks! I should have thought of that but I thought that Double could hold an extremely large number.. I will switch to long and go from there.

I'll accept your answer after the 10 minute mandatory wait.